# Answering questions for higher dimensions

Tags: soft-question, intuition, big-list

This isn't a question about how to visualize higher dimensions, or how intuit them, or how unintuitive they are.

Rather, it's a hypothetical question about the kinds of questions that might be easier to answer (not necessarily prove, but to suggest) if we could visualize $n$ dimensions as easily as we could 2 or 3. As an example, it's not hard to imagine we would probably have a better idea about [kissing numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number_problem) if we could picture higher dimensions as easily as the euclidian plane.

What other kinds of (unsolved) problems might lend themselves to analysis more easily if we could intuit $n$ dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

When I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707778/characterization-of-volumes-of-lattice-cubes) question, multiple commenters were surprised to learn that there don't exist three orthogonal lines with latices coordinates and length $2$ in $3$D space. Multidimension geometry in general tends to be unintuitive because of how used to $2$D we are. In the same vein of thought, manifolds would be a lot easier to study.

A bucket-load of problems in graph theory would likely be easier, as it would grant us the ability to display extremely complex graphs without overlapping any edges. You really only need $3$D to do this, but many people find that hard to conceptualize.